# Why Primitive Data types are fixed with their memory?

Tags: java

My Question:

- Why are primitive data-types are fixed in size?
- How can collections grow their in size dynamically?

Suppose, primitive data-types also contain the feature or ability to grow in their size dynamically. We could then reduce data-types from 8 to some 4 like "**Integer**" for all group of Integer, Float, Short, Long and **float** for group of Float, Double. Why isn't their structure that way?

Any answer will be help full. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so many questions into a single question? most of this questions are available in google, try it.

Comment: Question is reflecting on ,only primitive types & difference between the primitive data types & collection

Comment: Why was this closed? This is a good question with a reasonable answer.

Comment: The short answer is that it is done for efficiency. The underlying hardware has a limit on what sized types it can operate on in a single CPU cycle. However, it is possible to represent arbitrarily-sized integer and floating point numeric tpes (up to available memory) in software despite these hardware limitations. In fact, the BigInteger class does just this. In some other program languages (e.g. Python), the fixed-sized types are abstracted away (e.g. in Python, the integer type uses the underlying hardware type when small enough, but then uses the software strategy when it gets big).

Comment: Thanks Michael.It will be good,if java can change primitive data-types to some kind of predefined objects like collections or something.Memory will be handled carefully,java will be 100% object oriented & Most of the confusion will be reduced. which cause from this type-conversions..etc things like that.

Answer (score 3):

Hardware primitives always have a defined size, otherwise you'd have difficulties with memory layout, converting bytes to primitives and vice versa, etc. Software primitives (built-in datatypes provided by a language) might not need to be fixed size but that would make memory operations and data transfer more complex operations.

As an example, if you were to read an integer from a file, how many bytes would you read? 1,2,4,8?

In memory you'd have a similar problem: if an object would consist of two short integers, i.e. 2x2 bytes, you'd need to move the second integer if the first needed to grow or even move the entire object. That would be a performance penalty which wouldn't be compensated by just the comfort of having only one integer type.

Collections on the other hand, can grow since they either reference different parts of the heap or copy their content into a larger portion of the heap if more space is needed.

Take `ArrayList` as an example. Internally it uses an array which is located in a contiguous block of memory (otherwise accessing the memory by justing using the address of the array and the index of the element wouldn't work) and if that array needs to grow, a bigger array is created and the original array is copied to the new one.

`LinkedList` on the other hand is distributed over the heap, since each entry only contains a reference to the previous and next entry as well as the element. This makes growing the list easier but accessing a certain element would require you to search all elements until the one you're interested is found.

Another example:

Take an array of `int` values: 1,2,3,4,5,6

An array list (note that the JDK doesn't provide for primitive lists but there are other libraries that do) could store them as follows (hex values, byte order irrelevant for this example):

```
//Those are hex bytes
|--- 1 ---| |--- 2 ---| |--- 3 ---| |--- 4 ---| |--- 5 ---| |--- 6 ---|
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 06
```

Now if you want to access element 4 (index 3) you just need to know the memory address of the first element and add `index * 4` bytes to get the position of the 4th element. Then read the next 4 bytes and you have the element value. (4 bytes because an `int` is defined as 32-bit i.e. 4 bytes).

Without that information you'd have to take more action to get the 4th element.

Now consider a linked list

```
Element 0 <-> Element 1 <-> Element 2 <-> Element 3 <-> Element 4 <-> Element 5
  |             |             |             |             |             |
  v             v             v             v             v             v              
Value 1       Value 2       Value 3       Value 4       Value 5       Value 6
```

In memory the elements might be layed out like this:

```
 Element 5, other stuff, Element 3, Element 4, other stuff, Element 0, Element 2, Element 1
```

As you can see, the elements can be *anywhere* in the memory and thus you can't just access the 4th element by using a memory address, an index and the size of an element. Instead, you'd have to start at element 0 locate element 1 then 2 etc. until you have found the element you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,it will be good if you provide an explanatory answer or at least provide me some reference .

Comment: It's not true that "Primitives always have a fixed size", unless you are referring to Java, specifically. BigInteger demonstrates that the size of a numeric type is constrained only by memory, and some other languages take the approach of making the equivalent of BigInteger as their primary numeric type.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I'd say that primitives always have a fixed size for a defined architecture/platform. True, an int might be 16-, 32-, 64-bit depending on the system, but for that system an int needs to be defined in size. In the context of memory operations I'd call `BigInteger` an object rather than a primitive, which doesn't tell what is the _basic_ numeric type in a language.

Comment: @Thomas I think there may be a misunderstanding. What I was getting at was that "primitive" is a language concept. Yes, there is an underlying hardware-level primitive. However, the fact that the language emulates 64-bit integers on 32-bit platforms demonstrates that this is a language-level concept. I was challenging the assertion that fixed-sized primitives holds true always (across all languages). This is the case in Java, but other languages may have builtin types that are defined by the language (and not in the language).

Comment: @Thomas ... to add to that, BigInteger is not a primitive because it can be defined within the language (even if it is a part of the standard library), but one could easily imagine an alternative universe in which it was a primitive (e.g. designed to look and feel like a regular integer with standard operators and supported at the JVM level such that it is "special", a.k.a., a primitive).

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan you're right, what I meant was hardware primitives or close-to-hardware primitives which need fixed sizes for efficient operations. I updated my answer accordingly. To be efficient a language would still need to know the size of a primitive, even if that size might be flexible. But determining and changing that size at runtime is still an efficiency problem and removing fixed-size primitives in favor of dynamically sized ones would not be a great move for Java, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The primitive data types are the building blocks of more complex types. Ultimately, every type is composed of a number of primitive types and/or arrays.

The reason the primitives are fixed are:

1. They are supposed to match the primitive types that are supported on contemporary computers. For example, IEEE double values.
2. To facilitate portability. For example, in java, you know the range of your `int` type - no matter on what machine it runs. (Look at c, where there is confusion in this regard).

Comment: Wouldn't an unlimited size facilitate portability even more? You're right that Java improves over C and C++ in this regard, but a large part of the limitation in C, C++, and Java has to do with the hardware limitations.

Comment: No, @MichaelAaronSafyan, an unlimited byte size, for instance, would make communication with external sources (files, network) impossible. Moreover, an unlimited double size would crash many programs, since most numbers (0.1 for example) cannot be represented exactly in finite memory.

Comment: Well, an unlimited "byte" would certainly be unfortunate, but one could easily imagine the numeric types having infinite precision (although even with an unlimited "byte", one could always do "& 0xFF" to truncate to a byte). The "0.1" example is an issue specifically because of the representation; there are other representations (e.g. fractional) that don't have that issue. One could even imagine a real-valued type that switched between decimal, binary, rational, etc. based on the value stored (perhaps even with a bit to indicate the last digit repeats infinitely).

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan "& 0xff" doesn't help when you communicate with another program (written in unknown language) and the only thing you know is that it will give you 5 bytes of data. But what if your java bytes are currently 17 bits? We'd need a primitive type "real_byte" or some such. Hence. Regarding float/double, they are primitive types precisely to make use of the hardware (i.e. IEEE numeric processors). What you have in mind is maybe nice, but in no way "primitive". So what you're saying is that primitive types should not be primitive. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: you have a good point regarding communicating with other programs. And I agree that it would be necessary to have a means to serialize/deserialize to a fixed-size (with truncation where necessary). My basic disagreement is the rationale given. Java could have made the primitives more object-like (like Smalltalk or Python). Efficiency of basic integer operations and carrying over the way of thinking from C and C++ are more accurate reasons than the rationale given in your answer for Java primitives being out-of-place in the type system and having a fixed size.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan IMHO, the question is not what could have been if the Java designers had choosen differently. I understood the question was about the current status quo.

Comment: agreed. However, the answer should explain the rationale for the status quo, and what I'm saying is that I believe the answer you gave is rationalizing rather than giving the actual explanation for why this choice was made.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I do not speculate about why the decision to have primitve types at all was made, hence I am not rationalizing that decision.